# How to calculate Days between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to build a scalar function that calculates the days between two dates:

```
'20/03/2014'-'01/02/2015'=312
```

Some indications

```
all month=30 days
1 year =360 days
the two dates are add to calculation
```

I tested

```
select DATEDIFF(DAY,'20/03/2014','01/02/2015')
```

but the result is =318 and this for me is wrong (the correct result is 312)

I tested also

```
Select datediff(month, '01/02/2014',  '28/02/2014') * 30 - (DATEPART(day,'01/02/2014') - datepart(day,  '28/02/2014'))
```

and the result was 28 and that is false because the result should be 30 days 
thanks in advance

Comment: Please read here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

Comment: Your question does not really make sense.  Why isn't the built-in `datediff()` function sufficient?  If not, please provide sample data and desired results, preferably in a table format so we can read it.

Comment: What do you mean by `all month = 30 days and 1 year = 360 days`?  If you are specifying your own calendar, then of course the built in calendar functions aren't going to work.

Comment: I agree with Gordon, I don't know why you'd basically want to ignore the correct function and create your own incorrect function? We need some sanity to this question

Comment: Gordon Linoff, the datediff() is based on year=365 days and I want to calculate days based on 360 days a year(accounting domains)

Comment: http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=105369 This might be of some use

Comment: Yes TTeeple ,I use 360-day calendar (method of measuring durations used in financial markets) in excel, the function DAYS360 exist but not in sql server

Comment: You should have stated in your question that that you were using a 360 day calendar for financial markets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give you a datediff for a 360 day calendar:

Exclusive date range:

```
if datepart(day, @date2) = datepart(day,dateadd(day, -1,(Cast(Cast(datepart(year, @date2) as varchar) + '-' + Cast(datepart(month, @date2) + 1 as varchar) + '-01' as date))))
begin 
   Select datediff(month, @date1, @date2) * 30 - (DATEPART(day, @date1) - 30)
end
else if datepart(day, @date1) = datepart(day,dateadd(day, -1,(Cast(Cast(datepart(year, @date1) as varchar) + '-' + Cast(datepart(month, @date1) + 1 as varchar) + '-01' as date))))
begin 
   Select datediff(month, @date1, @date2) * 30 - (30 - datepart(day, @date2))
end
else
begin
   Select datediff(month, @date1, @date2) * 30 - (DATEPART(day, @date1) - datepart(day, @date2))
end
```

Inclusive date range:

```
if datepart(day, @date2) = datepart(day,dateadd(day, -1,(Cast(Cast(datepart(year, @date2) as varchar) + '-' + Cast(datepart(month, @date2) + 1 as varchar) + '-01' as date))))
begin 
   Select datediff(month, @date1, @date2) * 30 - (DATEPART(day, @date1) - 30) + 1
end
else if datepart(day, @date1) = datepart(day,dateadd(day, -1,(Cast(Cast(datepart(year, @date1) as varchar) + '-' + Cast(datepart(month, @date1) + 1 as varchar) + '-01' as date))))
begin 
   Select datediff(month, @date1, @date2) * 30 - (30 - datepart(day, @date2)) + 1
end
else
begin
   Select datediff(month, @date1, @date2) * 30 - (DATEPART(day, @date1) - datepart(day, @date2)) + 1
end
```

The If's check to see if either of the dates are the last day of the month. If they are then they treat it as the 30th since each month needs to be 30 days.

It calculates the number of months, multiplies by 30 and then the difference in days following this.

If you run this year to year with dates it will give 360, if you use your example it gives 311 but that's correct.

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/5791/0

Comment: Would have to add 1 to the end if you want to make it an inclusive range.  30-20 = 10 but that is exclusive.

Comment: Yeah exactly. I did do that originally but then I just felt like I didn't agree with it ha. I've updated my answer to include both now

Comment: Thank you Christian but when I execute query like this :                                  Select datediff(month, '01/01/2014',  '31/12/2015') * 30 - (DATEPART(day, '01/01/2014') - datepart(day,  '31/12/2015')) + 1  the result is 721 days (360*2=720 days)!!!

Comment: Yes you need to use the exclusive one without the +1 on the end

Comment: Ok I've updated the code and the SQL Fiddle, hopefully this should give you what you're looking for although Exclusively 01/02/2014 - 28/02/2014 will be 29 as it's 30 days - 1 day

Comment: @ChristianBarron : Can you please explain the if condition of your query?

Comment: Updated with a brief explanation